# Muti language support in single web page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, web-applications, internationalization

I have come across a requirement which I have never experienced before. 
I have a web page in which I have to show two language equivalent of a sentence. Like

How are you? (In english)
¿Cómo está usted (In Spanish)

So far, I have used the concept of Internalization which would change the locale and convert complete web page (other than database driven values) into the selected locale.

If the locale is set to Spanish, complete form will be displayed in Spanish. Here requirement is that both language string should be displayed next to each one.

**Update:**
Here is the image of my sample web page.
[image]

Comment: What is your problem? Why don't you just display these two sentences, one in English and one in Spanish?

Comment: I would like to display those sentences in my page through I18n.

Comment: Your problem just seems to be that you either used the wrong character encoding to retrieve the text of your question from whatever source you're getting them from (hint: mentioned it in your question), or that you have the character encoding wrong when you generate the output. Typically you want to use an UTF-8 character encoding on your output, but you must also indicate that in the HTTP response headers.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to do it dynamically by defining the `ResourceBundle` and then passing the `locale` to it, here Iam passing a `Dutch locale` and you should then have in your `resouces folder` the resource files, in my case I had `Messages.properties` for English, `Messages_nl.properties` for Dutch:

```
Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("nl", "NL");
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages", defaultLocale);
```

Then you can use the strings that you want as follows:

```
 String greeting = resourceBundle.getString("hello");
```

So in your case you need to define two ResourceBundle objects, each for English and Spanish.